# how to create nested and custom json format for the datafarme

Tags: json, dataframe, group-by

i want to create sub-categories from the existing data frame
data frame column consists of (sample table) my changes required at the columns level not any changes in the data like a set of columns are the and column names 3 different suffixes (few with similar column names and other column names)
example like
|payer_id|payer_name|halo_payer_name|delta_payer_name|halo_desc|delta_desc|halo_operations|delta_notes|halo_processed_data|delta_processed_data|extra|insurance_company|

I want it to be grouped in this halo group  halo_payer_name|halo_desc|halo_operations|halo_processed_data|

I want it to be grouped in this delta group  delta_payer_name|delta_desc|delta_notes|delta_processed_data|

and the remaining columns as one group
so when converted to JSON it would come in this layout

```
{
    "schema": {
        "fields": [{
                "payer_details": [{
                        "name": "payer_id",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "payer_name",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "extra",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "insurance_company",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "halo": [{
                        "name": "halo_payer_name",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "halo_desc",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "halo_operstions",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "halo_processed_data",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "delta": [{
                        "name": "delta_payer_name",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "delta_desc",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "delta_notes",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "delta_processed_data",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "pandas_version": "1.4.0"
    },
    "masterdata": [{
        "payer_details": [{
            "payer_id": "",
            "payer_name": "",
            "extra": "",
            "insurance_company": ""
        }],
        "halo": [{
            "halo_payer_name": "",
            "halo_desc": "",
            "halo_operations": "",
            "halo_processed_data": "",
                    }],
        "delta":[{
            "delta_payer_name": "",
            "delta_desc": "",
            "delta_notes": "",
            "delta_processed_data": "",
                    }]
    }]
}
```

for this type of situation i couldn't find a solution as it is a **column based grouping instead of data-based grouping**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so came across this post today it helped with my situation (adding data from a data frame and using it to create looped data and insert it into a dict and then convert the whole into a JSON file)
the ref that was helpful to me is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31181830/adding-item-to-dictionary-within-loop)
so the solution for this question goes like this

```
schema={
    "schema": {
        "fields": [{
                "payer_details": [{
                        "name": "payer_id",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "payer_name",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "extra",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "insurance_company",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "halo": [{
                        "name": "halo_payer_name",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "halo_desc",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "halo_operstions",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "halo_processed_data",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "delta": [{
                        "name": "delta_payer_name",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "delta_desc",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "delta_notes",
                        "type": "string"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "delta_processed_data",
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "pandas_version": "1.4.0"
    },
    "masterdata": []
}
```

derived the schema above as i have desired

```
payer_list=[]
for i in df.index:
  case={
        "payer_details": [{
            "payer_id": "{}".format(df['payer_id'][i]),
            "payer_name": "{}".format(df['payer_name'][i]),
            "extra": "{}".format(df['extra'][i]),
            "insurance_company": "{}".format(df['insurance_company'][i])
        }],
        "halo": [{
            "halo_payer_name": "{}".format(df['halo_payer_name'][i]),
            "halo_desc": "{}".format(df['halo_desc'][i]),
            "halo_operations": "{}".format(df['halo_operations'][i]),
            "halo_processed_data": "{}".format(df['halo_processed_data'][i]),
                    }],
        "delta":[{
            "delta_payer_name": "{}".format(df['delta_payer_name'][i]),
            "delta_desc": "{}".format(df['delta_desc'][i]),
            "delta_notes": "{}".format(df['delta_notes'][i]),
            "delta_processed_data": "{}".format(df['delta_processed_data'][i]),
                    }]
    }
  payer_list.append(case)
schema["masterdata"] = payer_list
```

created and empty list and run the loop and included in the empty list and joined or linked to the schema